# jstack - well-known file is not secure

Tags: java, jvm, jstack

I am running tomcat 5.5 on x86_64 CentOS 5.7 using 32-bit Oracle Java 1.6.0.

JVM process used by tomcat has 6421 pid. Tomcat is working fine.

When run `jstack` it fails with:

```
[root@mybox ~]# jstack 6421
6421: well-known file is not secure
```

To get any reasonable output, I need to use force option:

```
[root@mybox ~]# jstack -F 6421
Attaching to process ID 6421, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 17.0-b16
Deadlock Detection:

No deadlocks found.
(...)
```

The **questions** are:

1. what does the error message *"well-known file is not secure"* mean?
2. what is the "well-known" file?
3. why/when does the `jstack` command not work without a force option?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How long has tomcat been running? CentOS / RHEL unhelpfully delete files from /tmp after a few days (I forget how many).

Comment: @PaulCager: I restarted about 1 minute before running `jstack`

Comment: The same applies to running `jmap` to perform a heap dump.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This is probably due to the file in /tmp used to communicate with the process having different permissions than the one the *jstack* gets. The file in question is /tmp/hsperfdata_$USER/$PID.

Don't know why it works with -F as the man page just says "Force a stack dump when 'jstack [-l] pid' does not respond."

Comment: I had the same problem, because I was not in the same group as the hsperfdata* file. Changing my group via "newgrp other-group" worked.

Comment: I am running as root. Running jstack or jcmd and still prints the same message. There is a folder /tmp/hsperfdata_root/pid and it has access.

Comment: @dmachop The uid:gid being used to run `jstack` has to match the uid:gid of the well-known file. Running as root doesn't override the check - you can `sudo -u youruser -g yourgroup jstack ...` to become the correct uid:gid.

Comment: In fact, it's `/tmp/.java_pid<pid>`.

Answer (score 28):

when `-F` is used, the *jvm* will be **frozen**.

If you can find the `file: /tmp/hsperfdata_$USER/$PID`. Just try to switch to the `$USER`, and then `exec jstack`. You are running with "**root**", but that process may not belong to root.

if `$USER` does not have a login shell (i.e. daemon users), and thus can not switch to that user, you can work around this by using `sudo -u $USER jstack $PID`

Comment: if $USER does not have a login shell (i.e. daemon users), and thus can not switch to that user, you can work around this by using `sudo -u $USER jstack $PID`.

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem when i tried to run `jstack` as `root`.

Once i switched to another user it worked immediately.

Comment: Yep this worked for me.  Run my application (jvmtop) as the same user that the java process is running as and the error message and failure went away...

Answer (score 7):

You need to run the jstack command as the user that owns the java process :

For example if your java application is owned by a user called `java-user` :

```
sudo -u java-user jstack -l <pid>
```

Answer (score 4):

I just would like to add that you might need to specify your /tmp directory by -J option, since not all apps use the the default one

```
jstack -J-Djava.io.tmpdir=PATH -l PID
```

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error running:

```
watch -n .5 "jstack 26259"
```

Doing as sudo it works:

```
sudo watch -n .5 "jstack 26259"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to worry about user and can work as root and are okay to kill the process, you could use this last resort:

```
kill -s SIGQUIT $PID
```

This will write the thread dump to your console log, for example, in case of Tomcat, that would require grepping for "Full Thread" that is the beginning of the thread dump in logs/catalina.out and then getting the tdump file as:

```
DUMP_IDX=`grep -n 'Full thread' logs/catalina.out | tail -1 | cut -d':' -f1`
sed -n $DUMP_IDX,1000000000000000000p logs/catalina.out > jstack-kill-thread-dump-0309.tdump
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the one liner I use to make sure I'm always using the correct user permissions:

```
proc="my-process-name"; pid=`pgrep -f "${proc}"`; sudo -u "#`ps axo uid,pid | grep "${pid}" | tr -s " " | cut -f2 -d" "`" /usr/bin/jstack -l "${pid}" > /mnt/dumps/"${proc}"-`date +%s`.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides running with the same user, make sure that the group id of the user running jstack/jmap is also the same from the process.

Take a look at the [source code that checks for file permission](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/solaris/native/sun/tools/attach/LinuxVirtualMachine.c) (line 347). We can see that the function getting the group id is not an array, so it could be possible that the user has other groups, which started the process.

You might have to change the primary group from the user:

`#usermod -g group -G user user`

Answer (score -1):

Probably the easiest way is:

see the owner of the process by
 ps -ef | grep "process name"

then switch to that user and run the command.

jcmd PID GC.run or any other java utility

One thing i noticed that nobody discussed here is;  you also need to have JAVA_HOME variable set. check this by
echo $JAVA_HOME

Answer (score -1):

To successfully use the jstack, you should be running it with the same user as the process.