# How to use btrace

Tags: java, btrace

I want to study btrace.

java process user is yubaofu

yubaofu@btrace `sudo sh /home/yubaofu/study/btrace/bin/btrace 24234 JInfo.class`
well-known file is not secure

yubaofu@btrace `sh /home/yubaofu/study/btrace/bin/btrace 24234 JInfo.class` 
Connection refused

[I find a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9100149/jstack-well-known-file-is-not-secure)

how to solve it ?

os:ubuntu12 
jdk:jdk7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the file /tmp/hsperfdata_$USER/$PID. what's the $USER exactly ? Make sure it's the same user that you initialize btrace with.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this issue when attaching btrace to a process that has already been attached to. The workaround I found was

```
killall -KILL java
```

which simply kills all the java processes.