# JAVA Print Heap Dump

Tags: java, heap-memory, heap-dump

I work with Java 1.7 and I want to print `Heap Dump` from java

```
...
Object heapDump=.... ;
...

System.out.println(heapDump);
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `jmap`:

```
jmap -dump:format=b,file=heap.bin <pid>
```

refer to  [`Java 7` jmap tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jmap.html).

Comment: jmap -dump:format=b,file=/tmp/heap.bin 3894 throws exeption
3894: well-known file is not secure

Comment: You should try changing the file location to somewhere accessible, see similar issue and resolution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9100149/jstack-well-known-file-is-not-secure

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean.html) for creating a heap dump programmatically.

Comment: thows error java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: sun.management.Flag.initialize()V

Comment: @javagc What exactly did you do ? Which Hotspot version / vendor do you have ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't print the Heap Dump directly using S.O.P Statement. But you can dump all the data in a file. 
JVM will create heap dump every time when your application throws an `OutOfMemoryError`. `HeapDumpPath` is used to set location of heap dumps.

We can also use `jmap` from our code. Assume name,pid are the fileds retrieving. To get a pid from code use we need to use `java.lang.management.ManagementFactory`.

```
String name = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName();
String pid = name.substring(0, name.indexOf("@"));
After that we can start jmap process like this:
String[] cmd = { "jmap", "-dump:file=D:\\temp\\heapdumps\\dump.bin", pid };
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```